# In Wordpress Is there a way to display single post in a page so that the permalink part for a page remains in the URL?

Tags: wordpress

So I have a page named *events* which lists posts from *events* category.

Permalink of this page is like this

```
 domain.com/en/events/
```

When I click on post link on that page then the permalink changes to

```
domain.com/en/post-title/
```

But I would like it to be

```
 domain.com/en/events/post-title/
```

Anyway to achieve that?

**UPDATE:**

I'm thinking I could achieve the above if I make **event** page parent of those posts but I am not sure if this is possible? Post having for a parent a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. I'm posting it here so that it might help out others with the same issue.

I found [this article](http://www.gravitationalfx.com/how-to-set-a-page-as-the-parent-of-a-wordpress-custom-post-type/) which explains how to achieve what I want.

What needs to be done is to set that **event** Page to be parent of a WordPress Custom Post Type and then URL slug from the server root needs to be rewriten to include the path /events/

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/) is a good to go [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/)  for this situation. However you have to manually change post's permalink in each admin post section. See image below:

[image]

Comment: Looks interesting. Will check it out.

Comment: I added a picture on how to modify a url.

Answer (score 1):

in the permalink structure have it set up like this: domain.com/%category%/post-name/%

Comment: That wouldn't work in my case as I would need something like %/page-name/% %/post-name/% but %/page-name/% doesn't exist. But thanks for giving me an idea. Now I'm trying to make page parent of those posts.

Comment: there is a plugin that can give static pages also a category. I hope you can solve it. Have a good day